# See methods and properties of an add-in library

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I have an add-in of ms-project, which has a COM Add In library (OnePager pro).
How can I know what methods and properties are available in it?
Thanks.

Comment: Set a reference to the library then hit F2 and select the library from the dropdown.

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't appear at the reference list, so I do late binding. Is there an option to see the properties in this way?

Comment: It may very well be that the makers of the add-in have not provided an interface to view the libraries content.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply.